# Sensor solution for motion detection on very fast / short events

Tags: image-processing, sensors, motion-detection, leap-motion, realsense

I'm searching for possible solutions to build up an system which recognizes very fast motions above a sensor. Just imagine a scenario like a sensor which is facing to the top of the room and waiting for a person or object to jump over it. Or detecting a football passing the sensor with high speed. This means the interval of "change" will be very short. I'm aware that this is a typical light-barrier scenario. But i want to check out alternative ways to solve this.

The system should fullfill the following requirements:

must have:

- low latency
- low rate of "false positive" detections or error susceptibility
- small installation (hardware)

nice to have:

- no need for microcontroller programming by using an SDK/API or something similar

I'm facing to the direction of using light barriers in combination with Raspberry-PI or Arduino. But this would cause an additional implementation to build a bridge between my application (Unity3D) and the sensor.

Questions/Ideas:

- Has anyone experience in using solutions like **Leap-Motion** or **Intel RealSense** for such a purpose ? As there are plenty sensors in these devices, maybe it would be an option to use only a specific part of them.
- Would image processing (OpenCV) being abled to process such small events  with an appropriate latency ?
- What about using a smartphone with it's wide variety of integrated sensors ?
- Are there maybe light barries or suitable sensors with an comfortable interface or API ?

I would really appreciate any kind of suggestions / thoughts about this topic

best regards and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Wireless activity detection](https://store.ncd.io/product/iot-wireless-activity-detection-sensor/) sensor which will to your expectation but since, I am beginner to adapt these kind of solution, You should check [product manual](https://ncd.io/iot-wireless-activity-detection-sensor-product-manual/) first which will suggest the best.

Comment: looks usable. I will take a look at the solution and share the feedback in this thread. Thx!